# Finding audio peaks in video files

Tags: linux, video, audio, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of video files that I want to process. I want to write a program that can find the audio peaks in each file and return the times where those peaks occurred.

I've looked for a lot of different APIs in different languages but couldn't get any of them to work. I am partial to php and java, so if anyone knows any good audio processing libraries in those languages that would be great! But really I don't care too much about the language. I will need to run this program on a cron.

Also, is it possible to use system calls to ffmpeg from within a script to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How accurate do these times need to be?  Sample-accurate?  Frame-accurate?  Down to the second?  The reason I ask, is that you can easily find these peaks when separating the audio from the video, but syncing them back up again might be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

While I've only used this to work directly with audio files, the [python wrapper around theechonest](http://echonest.github.io/remix/)'s audio analysis service can slurp in the audio from various video files.  It uses ffmpegs shared libs to do this, though I find this wrapper much easier to work with via python then the command line.

Of particular interest within the api is echonest.video which is, to quote the docs:

> Framework that turns video into silly putty.

I'd add a couple other helpful urls but apparently I can only add one since I don't have a reputation...

anyway, hopefully that's a helpful lead.